# How to put some texts besides a smartdiagram?

Tags: tikz-pgf, diagrams, smartdiagram

I am writing a code using the smartdiagram package. My working code is as follows:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{smartdiagram}
\begin{document}
    \centering
    \smartdiagramset{set color list={orange!40, orange!40, orange!40 ,orange!40}}
    \tikzset{priority arrow/.append style={rotate=180,anchor=0,xshift=30}}
    \smartdiagram[priority descriptive diagram]{Krohn-Rhodes form of EEG signals, Flat EEG, Magnetic Contour plane, Fuzzy Topographic Topological Mapping}
    
\end{document}
```

which produces a diagram as follows:

[image]

How can I add some texts (years) beside the diagram that looks as follows:

[image]

How can I achieve this? Please help.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The `smartdiagram` package creates nodes named `modulex`, with x a number from 1 to n. You can remember these nodes by adding `remember picture` to the style of the diagram and referring to the nodes in a new `tikzpicture` with the `overlay` property. The exact positioning can be done using `xshift` and `yshift` in the new nodes.

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{smartdiagram}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
\begin{document}
    \centering
    \smartdiagramset{set color list={orange!40, orange!40, orange!40 ,orange!40}}
    \tikzset{priority arrow/.append style={rotate=180,anchor=0,xshift=30},every picture/.append style={remember picture}}
    \smartdiagram[priority descriptive diagram]{Krohn-Rhodes form of EEG signals, Flat EEG, Magnetic Contour plane, Fuzzy Topographic Topological Mapping}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[overlay]
    \node[left=of module4,xshift=-1mm,yshift=1mm] {2000};
    \node[left=of module3,xshift=-1mm,yshift=-1mm] {2006};
    \node[left=of module2,xshift=-1mm,yshift=-1mm] {2008};
    \node[left=of module1,xshift=-1mm,yshift=1mm] {2011};
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Result:

[image]